# Converting shapefiles (.shp) to CAD (.dwg ) format using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, dwg

How to convert shapefiles  to .dwg format using QGIS 1.7.0?

Answer (score 5):

QGIS can output **DXF** files by rightclick on the layer and `Save as`. Every CAD software should be able to read that. A **DWG** driver is available, but for license issues not  implemented:

http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DxfDwg

Comment: Right click on the layer → Export → Save Features As ...

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible in QGIS but Google tells me there are Autocad plugins for importing Shapefiles http://www.cadtutor.net/forum/showthread.php?2004-Converting-shp-files-to-dwg

Answer (score 0):

Export a dxf then convert that to dwg with DoubleCAD XT

http://www.doublecad.com/DoubleCAD/DoubleCADXTv3/tabid/1100/Default.aspx

Answer (score -1):

QGIS can konvert shapefiles to DXF.
Next step is to use https://cloudconvert.com/dxf-to-dwg

BUT you'll need Dropbox, Google Drive, OneDrive or Box to store your DXF files, and the outputfile is also placed in Dropbox, Google Drive, OneDrive or Box.

You can only use the free version for 25 conversions minuttes a day.