# Converting shapefiles to CAD files?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, convert, arcgis-9.3, cad

I'm having difficulty in converting shapefiles to cad file. I'm currently using the ArcGIS 9.3.1 version and I tried to convert it using the `toolbox> conversion tool> to cad> export to cad` route... the conversion was partly successful but then it doesn't have any attributes when I tried to open it in ArcMap.

When I try to open it in Autocad I can't see a thing...

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

According to the question I think that you want to convert shape files to CAD format.

**In ArcGIS :**

Under Output Type

> select the appropriate CAD format

and then try.

Click [here](https://confluence.cornell.edu/display/GIS/Convert+shapefiles+and+other+vector+data+to+CAD+format+%28ArcGIS%29) for the steps.

**In  QGIS :**

I think its not possible and  dont know which version you are using . Try going through [Converting shapefiles (.shp) to CAD (.dwg ) format using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48840)